# How to use git commands during a github action?

Tags: python, git, github, github-actions

Trying to auto-apply black and isort to only the files changed on some python code with github actions during a pull request on a self-hosted runner, and after that commit to the PR. But get errors such as `Not a git repository` on some of the steps. Here is my workflow file:

```
name: Autolint

on:
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize]

jobs:
  run-linters:
    name: Run linters
    runs-on: self-hosted
    container:
      image: edlut/azion:monster-action-base
      options: --privileged

    steps:
    - name: Install git 
      run: |
        apt-get install -y git
        git --version
        echo "Path is ... $PATH"
        PATH=$PATH:$(which git)
        echo "Path is ... $PATH"

    - uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Debug - Check if .git folder exists
      run: |
        ls -lah

    - name: Install Python dependencies
      run: pip3 install black isort

    - name: Apply Black
      env:
        BRANCH: ${{ github.head_ref }}
      run: |
        echo "Branch is ... ${BRANCH}"
        git diff --name-only "$GITHUB_BASE_REF..${BRANCH}" | grep .py | xargs black -l 119

    - name: Apply isort
      env:
        BRANCH: ${{ github.head_ref }}
      run: |
        git diff --name-only "$GITHUB_BASE_REF..${BRANCH}" | xargs isort

    - name: Check for modified files
      id: git-check
      run: echo ::set-output name=modified::$(if git status | grep "nothing to commit"; then echo "false"; else echo "true"; fi)

    - name: Push changes
      if: steps.git-check.outputs.modified == 'true'
      run: |
        git config --global user.name 'My Name'
        git config --global user.email 'my-name@gmail.com'
        git remote set-url origin https://x-access-token:${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}@github.com/${{ github.repository }}
        # git commit -am "style: Apply Black style"
        # git push
```

Can anybody help me out on how to achieve this?

Comment: From the `checkout` actions readme page, _When Git 2.18 or higher is not in your PATH, falls back to the REST API to download the files._. What version of `git` is installed and does the current folder contain a `.git` folder?

Comment: Git is using version 2.25.1, and the current folder doesn't have a `.git` folder. It should be created when cloning the project right?

Comment: Correct. If there is no `.git` folder, then git commands won't work

Comment: OK! Manage to get the `.git` folder and have `git` in the PATH variable, however now I have a different error: it says "fatal: ambiguous argument 'dev..auto-lint': unknown revision or path not in the working tree". Weird part is that this works fine locally. Issue occurs only in github actions. I've updated the code. `dev` is the source branch (or target) where this PR will be merged, and `auto-lint` is the branch where the PR is being developed.

Comment: That's probably because the ref does not exist in your git refs (`ls .git/refs/heads`), so you need to do a `git fetch --all` or `git fetch origin auto-lint dev`. At this point, I would recommend, you just use the `git` command to fetch the repo and do everything else you need, rather than relying on the `checkout` action. The `checkout` action is useful if you just want to work with the repo's files, not for working with refs and other git internals

Comment: @Vini.g.fer how did you get the .git folder? Maybe add an Answer for it?

Answer (score 19):

```
name: Version Build

on:
  push:
    branches: [ develop ]

jobs:
  build-version:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Git checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
      with:
        fetch-depth: '0'
    - name: git
      run: |
        # setup the username and email. I tend to use 'GitHub Actions Bot' with no email by default
        git --version
        git config user.name "GitHub Actions Bot"
        git config user.email "<>"
        git status
        git tag
        git describe
```